# Why cant we edit/delete flags?

Tags: feature-request, flags

This question: [Is there an "and" operator for regular expressions in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546871/is-there-an-and-operator-for-regular-expressions-in-javascript#comment45407120_28546871) was very unclear at first, so I raised a flag for unclearness. When the author finally clarified some, I wanted to declare it as a duplicate, but couldn't, so I used a modertor attention flag. As soon as I finished flagging it, a user posted what looked like the exact answer the author needs, but I cannot remove my flag.

EDIT: OP states that the answer did not answer his question, but my request remains.

Why can we not remove or edit flags within a reasonable time frame (maybe 10 minutes?)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Agreed